# YouTube API Search v3 - Start index?

Tags: api, search, youtube

I'm using the YouTube Search API to grab 5 videos per time under a specific keyword. But I've been trying and trying, but couldent find the parameter for the **start index**. Does anyone know how to add it, so it gets the next 5 videos etc..?

Current URL I have:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=wiz+khalifa&type=video&key=AIzaSyB9UW36sMDA9rja_J0ynSYVcNY4G25
```

Answer (score 3):

In the results of your first query, you should get back a nextPageToken field.
When you make the request for the next page, you must send this value as the pageToken.

So you need to add pageToken=XXXXX to your query, where XXXXX is the value you received in nextPageToken.

Hope this helps